# IntelliJ con JavaFX: error al cambiar ubicacion del controlador

Tags: java, javafx, controller, intellij-idea, model-view-controller

estoy trabajando con IntelliJ para crear una aplicación usando JavaFx. Por defecto, las clases se guardan en *main.java.com.example.myProject* y los .fxml en *main.resources.com.example.myProject*. Entonces, si tengo un archivo .fxml en ésta última ruta y su correspondiente controlador en la anterir ruta, anda todo bien. Pero si muevo el controlador a una nueva carpeta, por ejemplo, *main.java.com.example.myProject.controller* se rompe todo:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at javafx.fxml@19-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1857)
    at javafx.fxml@19-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1724)
    at javafx.base@19-ea/com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
    at javafx.fxml@19-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3324)
    at javafx.fxml@19-ea/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3287)
...
...
```

Desde el .fxml importo bien el controlador, no hay ningun problema de sintaxis. Entiendo que debe ser un problema que no encuentra la carpeta *controller*, pero no se como solucionarlo.

Para que quede mas claro, la estructura de ficheros es la siguiente

- src

  - main

    - java

      - com.example.myProject

        - controller

          - MainController.java (aca no funciona)
        - Main.java
        - MainController.java (aca si funciona)
    - resources

      - com.example.myProject

        - Main-view.fxml

Además, el Main.java tiene una escena que si la muestra, pero tomando el caso que no funciona, cuando aprito el boton no va a la otra escena y muesta el error de más arriba.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ajunto codigo importante

```
public class Main extends Application {
  @Override
  public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    Parent root =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("views/sceneA.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

    /* FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(Main.class.getResource("views/hello-view.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 900, 500);
    stage.setTitle("Tennis Tournament");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();

     */
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
}
```

controlador

```
public class SceneController {
private Stage stage;
private Scene scene;
private Parent parent;

public void switchToSceneA(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    parent =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("views/sceneA.fxml"));
    stage = (Stage) ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    scene = new Scene(parent);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public void switchToSceneB(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
    parent =  FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("views/SceneB.fxml"));
    stage = (Stage) ((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
    scene = new Scene(parent);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
}
```

En el archivo fxml se cambia correctamente el path al controlador correspondiente. Respecto a la segunda pregunta, tengo el archivo que indicas con la siguiente configuracion

```
module com.example.myProject { requires javafx.controls; requires javafx.fxml; opens com.example.myProject to javafx.fxml; exports com.example.myProject; opens com.example.myProject.controllers to javafx.fxml; exports com.example.myProject.controllers to javafx.controls; }
```

Comment: Al mover el controlador de sitio ¿estás cambiando también el atributo `fx:controller` del archivo FXML? ¿Estás utilizando una configuración modular (con module-info.java) o no modular?

Comment: @ArielCostas hola, si. En el archivo fxml se cambia correctamente el path al controlador correspondiente. Respecto a la segunda pregunta, tengo el archivo que indicas con la siguiente configuracion

module com.example.myProject {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;


    opens com.example.myProject to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.myProject;

    opens com.example.myProject.controllers to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.myProject.controllers to javafx.controls;
}

Answer (score 0):

En base al comentario en tu pregunta, el problema probablemente esté en el `module-info.java`. Según comentas, tu módulo está definido del siguiente modo:

```java
module com.example.myProject{
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    opens com.example.myProject to javafx.fxml;
    exports com.example.myProject;
    exports com.example.myProject.controllers;
    opens com.example.myProject.controllers to javafx.controls;
}
```

Basta con quitar `to javafx.controls` en la última línea para que `controllers` esté disponible globalmente.

---

Si no, siempre puedes deshacerte del módulo completamente. Trabajar con módulos se vuelve muy tedioso si empiezas a usar dependencias de cualquier tipo (`java.sql` para JDBC, dependencias externas de Maven o cualquier otra cosa que no sea JavaFX).

Con eliminar el `module-info.java` y cambiar el elemento `mainClass` del plugin de JavaFX en Maven para quitar `com.example.myProject/` del nombre; basta para que sea un proyecto no modular y no tener que gestionar nada de eso. Para ejecutar, se usa `mvn javafx:run` en una terminal (o en IntelliJ) y debería funcionar igual.